# Why does passing a char array as argument in a function and trying to modify inside the function shows segmentation error?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, constants

I have declared an array of char variables as below:

```
char word[256];
char plural[256];
```

It takes input inside the `main` function and copies to plural variable as below:

```
scanf("%s",&word);
strcpy(plural,word);
```

The input I provided is "Baby".

The main method call another function pluralize by passing both the variables as arguments as below:

```
void pluralize(word,plural);
```

Here is what I want to do with the pluralize method:

```
void pluralize(char word[], char plural[]){
    char textToBeAdded[] = "IES";   
    int i = strlen(plural);
    plural[i-1] = '\0';
    plural = strcat(plural, textToBeAdded);
    printf("Word is %s and plural is %s", word, plural);
    printf("\nRule is 1\n");
}
```

I am not using `char*` and using `char[]`, so it should be modifiable. But it shows a segmentation run time error. Why and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show a [mcve], not just a few snippets of code.

Comment: What is it that you give as input? It should be small enough to fit in the char array.

Comment: Also if `plural` is empty,  `plural[i-1] = '\0';` this line is undefined behavior.

Comment: i am using strcpy to copy word to plural. The input for word is "Baby". Also, please consider the scenarios which in case is not empty. Why would I use a empty char here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is with this statement:

```
scanf("%s",&word);
```

`word` is an array of `char`s. So to read into it, you just have to:

```
scanf("%s",word);
```